# Automorphism group of a putative strongly regular graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, permutation-groups, strongly-regular-graph

The smallest feasible parameters for which no strongly regular graph is known to exist are $(69,48,32,36)$, as per Brouwer's table. What is known on the automorphism group of such a graph?

Comment: This post is more as in the middle of a private email exchange than of a public discussion.

Answer (score 1):

According to Andries Brouwer, the latest reference for that question is:

Behbahani & Lam,
Strongly regular graphs with non-trivial automorphisms,
Discr Math 311 (2011) 132-144

It shows that any automorphism of prime order of that graph has order 2 or 3.